# Gas optimization of calldata input variables

Tags: solidity, gas

I have some external functions what receives `address` lists as `calldata` to save gas. I know that creating a copy from global variables inside functions can be useful to read less from blockchain variables, however I am not sure if doing the same with read-only calldata types will lead to less gas spending.

Is it make sense to prefer one of the below functions in order to save gas?

```
function testFunctionA (address[] calldata addressList) external {
    address[] memory path;
    path[0] = addressList[0];
    path[1] = addressList[0];

}
```

In this case I assume it doesn't make sense until I don't use `a1` or `a2` more than one time within the same function like in `testFunctionC`. Is it right? Or is it a better idea to copy list objects from `calldata` lists into local variables inside the function regardless how many times will I use them?

```
function testFunctionB (address[] calldata addressList) external {
    address a1 = addressList[0];
    address a2 = addressList[1];
    address[] memory path;
    path[0] = a1;
    path[1] = a2;

}

function testFunctionB (address[] calldata addressList) external {
    address a1 = addressList[0];
    address a2 = addressList[1];
    address[] memory path;
    path[0] = a1;
    path[1] = a2;
    path[2] = a1;
    path[3] = a2;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading about the topic the consequences are the following for me:

- Array reads by index should be avoided when you use the variable more
  than 1 time. It is cheaper to make a copy and use that inside the
  function.
- Create fixed length arrays if it is possible in the given situation.
  Initializing empty, non-fixed arrays and extend the size by pushing new objects will be more expensive.